# C++ Compiler doesn't recognize templated diamond

Tags: c++, templates, diamond-problem

Due to circumstances beyond my controll, I needed to create the following diamond in order to safely access and controll data in a common base class from different threads.

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
public:
    void writeLockT();
    void writeUnlockT();
    void readLockT();
    void readUnlockT();

    T* writeInstance();
    const T* readInstance();

private:
    SomeBuffer<T> m_buffer;
};

template <class T>
class Derived1 : public Foo, virtual public Base<T>
{
};

template <class T>
class Derived2 : public Bar, virtual public Base<T>
{
};

struct MyData
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    std::string name;
};

class Final: public Derived1<MyData>, public Derived2<MyData>
{
};
```

The class SomeBuffer is a custom container that rotates between 3 instances of T so that I can write 1 instance, without blocking access to those that want to read (they get the most recently written version of T, but not the version currently being written to).

Both Foo and Bar are interfaces (i.e.: classes with nothing but pure virtual methods).

The instances of these classes are stored as either Foo pointers or Bar pointers, but never as Base or DerivedX pointers (as the template is unknown at that point in the code).

This looks like a normal diamond of death if both Derived1 and Derived2 take the same class as template argument and yet I've noticed the following behavior:

The constructor of Base is called twice (I've tested it by placing the line "cout << this << std::endl" in the constructor of Base, the value of 'this' is different each time);

If I call a method in the base class, it's anyones guess which base class is called (tested in the same way as previous point), which means if I call writeLockT in one point and writeInstance at a differnt point, I get access to different instances of SomeBuffer (breaking the code).

Please note that the lock and unlock methods are called indirectly via virtual methods in the Foo and Bar (that get overloaded in Derived1 and Derived2), whereas the instance methods get called from within Final.

Why doesn't this work? There should only be one instance of Base with virtual inheritance, yet I have 2.

For the record my IDE is KDevelop4 for OpenSuse and changing is not an option (I'm at work).

My thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: I could not reproduce with VS2015 but can you try to make a Final template `template <class T> class Final : public Derived1<T>, public Derived2<T>` and instantiate it as `Final<MyData>`? Does it change anything?

Comment: I'm only getting the constructor of Base called once: https://ideone.com/PoQze8
Do any of your DerivedX hold an instance of Base maybe?

Comment: IDE does not matter. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @MikhailMaltsev I'm pretty sure I'm using GCC.

Comment: After running the code a few more times, I discovered that the source of my problem was between keyboard and chair. It turns out that the class containing the instance of 'Final'  was also derived of Base and that class was locked, but not Final. So the observation of having two instances of Base was indeed correct, I did have two 1 for final and 1 for the class containing it.

Should I make this comment the accepted answer?